# Как мне на примере использовать Laravel 8 model casts?

Tags: laravel

Я понимаю, что:

```
protected = casts [

 'id_admin'=> 'boollean'

];
```

Мы можем менять тип данных в колонке с одного на другой.
Но какая необходимость в этом? Мы же изначально создаем таблицы с определенным, подходящим типом данных для нашего проекта. Представим у меня 10000 пользователей и что дальше?

Comment: булевый тип не везде, например, есть, обычно в качестве него выступает байт.

Comment: СПС), но зачем мне касты, как мне применять в интернет магазине, или база данных сотрудников?

Comment: никто вас не обязывает применять этот функционал. Если потребности в этом нет, то и применять не надо.

Comment: В каких случаях эта потребность может понадобиться? Интернет магазин, вывод карточек или как? Или вывод статей, постов и так далее. Где мне это применять хоть маленький пример какой-нибудь?? Есть поля в базе данных  зачем нам может понадобиться необходимость менять тип данных полей??

Answer (score 1):

Самый базовый пример: `'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d'`. А в бд как правило данная дата хранится с типом timestamp а на выходе мы хотим получать (в определённых случаях) обрезая время или форматируя дату как мы хотим.

Далее. Очень часто данные хранятся в виде `json` в бд. И на выходе после формирования модели мы хотим сразу получать декодированный массив. и чтобы не делать везде `json_decode` мы можем сделать свой каст и указывать его в данном свойстве

```
protected $casts = [
    'options' => Json::class, // кастомный каст
];
```

Очень много примеров в документации. В php 8.1 можно использовать `Enum Casting`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ Дмитрий)

Comment: Это точно JSON храниться в виде строки и его нужно декодировать